# Check if a column is consecutive with groupby in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark dataframe that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
foo = pd.DataFrame({'group': ['a','a','a','b','b','c','c','c'], 'value': [1,2,3,4,5,2,4,5]})
```

I would like to create a new binary column `is_consecutive` that indicates if the values in the `value` column are consecutive by `group`.

The output should look like this:

```
foo = pd.DataFrame({'group': ['a','a','a','b','b','c','c','c'], 'value': [1,2,3,4,5,2,4,5],
'is_consecutive': [1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0]})
```

How could I do that in pyspark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lag` to compare values with the previous row and check if they are consecutive, then use `min` to determine whether all rows are consecutive in a given group.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'consecutive', 
    F.coalesce(
        F.col('value') - F.lag('value').over(Window.partitionBy('group').orderBy('value')) == 1, 
        F.lit(True)
    ).cast('int')
).withColumn(
    'all_consecutive', 
    F.min('consecutive').over(Window.partitionBy('group'))
)

df2.show()
+-----+-----+-----------+---------------+
|group|value|consecutive|all_consecutive|
+-----+-----+-----------+---------------+
|    c|    2|          1|              0|
|    c|    4|          0|              0|
|    c|    5|          1|              0|
|    b|    4|          1|              1|
|    b|    5|          1|              1|
|    a|    1|          1|              1|
|    a|    2|          1|              1|
|    a|    3|          1|              1|
+-----+-----+-----------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use  lead and subtract the same with the existing value then find max of the window, once done , put a condition saying return 0 is max is >1 else return 1

```
w = Window.partitionBy("group").orderBy(F.monotonically_increasing_id())

(foo.withColumn("Diff",F.lead("value").over(w)-F.col("value"))
 .withColumn("is_consecutive",F.when(F.max("Diff").over(w)>1,0).otherwise(1))
.drop("Diff")).show()
```

---

```
+-----+-----+--------------+
|group|value|is_consecutive|
+-----+-----+--------------+
|    a|    1|             1|
|    a|    2|             1|
|    a|    3|             1|
|    b|    4|             1|
|    b|    5|             1|
|    c|    2|             0|
|    c|    4|             0|
|    c|    5|             0|
+-----+-----+--------------+
```